# Workflow for managing client projects on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have a number of clients with simple cloud platform needs, usually just a maps API key or API key for some other API. Now that Google is enforcing a link to a billing account for each project, it becomes a bit more problematic to manage these API keys for clients. The process of creating an account, creating a project, assigning resources and restricting keys is more complex than clients can do on their own. Now that a credit card is required, I don't want to attach my company's credit card to their usage.

What is the best workflow for setting up cloud platform accounts for clients? Ideally, they would be able to log in to Cloud Console, add me as an administrator on their account with full access and I could take it from there. I want to avoid sharing passwords, and if possible, I want to avoid managing their credit card and payments.

Comment: The steps you outlined are the correct ones. Either your client creates a Billing Account and GCP account and adds your email address to IAM or you do it for them. Billing accounts are a separate account from GCP projects. You link projects to a billing account. I would create a nice document with detailed steps and screenshots to show your client how to set up their account and add/remove your account for management.

Comment: What IAM permissions do I need to create projects, add credentials to them, and link them to billing accounts?

I would actually hope that GCP would have documentation with detailed steps and screenshots on how to set up an account, add a billing account and add/remove a user for account management. The current documentation at https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects is WAY to complex for a client, not step by step and doesn't mention billing accounts.

Comment: I created a videolab that might help you. https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/